# What is the recommended elevation between the water table and the growing surface?

Tags: soil, water, permaculture

I'm starting to plan out my garden for the spring planting, and am trying to figure out how much surface I need between where the green part of the plants and the water table. I'm trying to have a big enough garden (about an acre of knocked down grass) this year so my local tree service can drop off their load of wood chips and pick enough vegetables for their family as payment so they remember to come back more often. A slow flowing creek runs right along the edge of my expansion zone.

My zone 4 planned planting includes:

- tomatoes/tomatillo
- cucumbers
- Stevia
- okahijiki(edible ground
- kale
- Nasturtium (edible ground cover)
- Thyme
- Basil
- Anise
- Thyme
- Carrots
- Longevity spinach
- Okra
- Ramps

Comment: It depends how free draining your soil is. In the best gardening conditions I ever had personally. the water table was about 12 inches below ground all the year round. If you dug a hole 18 inches deep, there was water in the bottom of it within a few hours. But the soil was about 50% sand and 50% river silt, very quick draining. Absolutely anything would grow. If you used tree prunings as plant supports, most of them took root in a few months without any tender loving care at all. We never tried germinating wood chips, but I wouldn't have been surprised if that would have been successful!